# Manually trigger Hammer.JS event?

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

How can I 'fire' a HammerJS tap event? For example if I've done this:

```
Hammer(myelem).on('tap', myFunction);
```

is there anything like

```
Hammer(myelem).fire('tap')
```

which will then call myFunction with a fake `ev`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [here](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Instance-methods#hammertimetriggergesture-eventdata)

```
Hammer(myelem).trigger('tap', eventData);
```

Keep in mind that the docs say:

> You shouldn't use this, this is an internally method use by the
>   gestures. Only use it when you know what you're doing! You can read
>   the sourcecode about how to use this.

So, just to be sure I would [check the source code on trigger](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/search?q=trigger&ref=cmdform), to see what they are doing.